# Have Chapter thumb appear on top of background box

Tags: backgrounds, chapterthumb

In the code given below, how do I get the chapter thumb to appear on top of the background box.

Current code hides the chapter thumb box:

[image]

Here is the code:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{addlines}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{varwidth}
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{marginfix}
\RequirePackage{zref-abspos}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{lightGrey}{gray}{0.94}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}
\newcommand\BoxColor{black}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Backgrounding commands
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Vertical lines
\newcommand{\backgroundThisPageGrey}{\bigVerticalLine{bigVerticalLineGrey}}
\newcommand{\backgroundThisPageColor}{\bigVerticalLine{mainColor}}

% Entire page area
\newcounter{background}[page]
\renewcommand{\thebackground}{\arabic{page}-\arabic{background}}

\newcommand{\backgroundAnchor}[1]{\leavevmode\zsavepos{background-#1}}

\newlength{\backgroundInnerTopSpace}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\startBackground}{O{0mm} O{0mm} O{\thebackground}}{% space_before_begin space_after_begin counter
    \setlength{\backgroundInnerTopSpace}{1em}\addtolength{\backgroundInnerTopSpace}{#2}%
    \vspace*{#1}\newline%
    \backgroundAnchor{begin-#3}\vspace*{\backgroundInnerTopSpace}\\%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\startBackgroundPageTop}{O{\thebackground}}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \node at (current page.north west) {\backgroundAnchor{begin-#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newlength{\depthLength}
\settodepth{\depthLength}{p}
\newlength{\backgroundInnerBottomSpace}
\newlength{\backgroundOuterBottomSpace}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\stopBackground}{O{0mm} O{0mm} O{\thebackground}}{% outer_space inner_space counter
    \setlength{\backgroundInnerBottomSpace}{2\depthLength}\addtolength{\backgroundInnerBottomSpace}{#2}%
    \vspace*{\backgroundInnerBottomSpace}%
    \setlength{\backgroundOuterBottomSpace}{1em}\addtolength{\backgroundOuterBottomSpace}{#1}
    \backgroundAnchor{end-#3}\vspace*{\backgroundOuterBottomSpace}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\stopBackgroundPageBottom}{O{\thebackground}}{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\node at (current page.south east) {\backgroundAnchor{end-#1}};}}

\tikzset{background/.style = {fill=lightGrey}}
\newcommand{\drawBackground}[1][\thebackground]{%
    \leavevmode%
    \stepcounter{background}%
    \zsavepos{background-draw-#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0mm]
        \fill[background] let
        \p1=(current page.west),
        \p2=(current page.east) in
        (\x1, \zposy{background-begin-#1}sp - \zposy{background-draw-#1}sp) rectangle
        (\x2, \zposy{background-end-#1}sp   - \zposy{background-draw-#1}sp);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ignorespaces
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Full width environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Saving some length as commands
\newlength{\wholeMargin}
\setlength{\wholeMargin}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\wholeMargin}{\marginparsep}

\newenvironment{whole}{%
    \centering
    \blockmargin
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0em}{-\wholeMargin}
}{%
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \unblockmargin
}

\fancypagestyle{ttt}{%

\fancyhf{}%

\fancyhead[RO]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
            \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
                text height=11.7in,align=center,anchor=north east]
                at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,0cm) $)
                {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{8cm}{%
                \centering\textcolor{white}{\hspace*{5in}\bfseries{\Large Test Of Text Here}}}}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \fancyhead[LE]{%
           \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=11.7in,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,0cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{8cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\hspace*{5in}\bfseries{\Large Test Of Text Here}}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
            }
            }

\pagestyle{ttt}

\begin{document}

    \vfill
    \drawBackground\startBackground
    \begin{whole}
        \footnotesize%
        {\color{mainColor}{Example of Table}}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \vspace*{0mm}{205 million}\\[1mm]
        \lipsum[1]
        
        \vspace*{3mm}{1\$ million}\\[1mm]
        \lipsum[2]
        
        \columnbreak
        \vspace*{0mm}{136 million}\\[1mm]
        Some words on Facebook in 2016.
        
        \vspace*{3mm}{10 milliom}\\[1mm]
        \lipsum[3]
        
        \vspace*{3mm}{527 billion}\\[1mm]
        \lipsum[4]
        \end{multicols}
    \end{whole}
    \stopBackgroundPageBottom


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the background in the foot instead of the head. The foot is created after the text body and so if will overwrite the text:

```
\fancyfoot[RO]{%<----foot
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
            \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
                text height=11.7in,align=center,anchor=north east]
                at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,0cm) $)
                {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{8cm}{%
                \centering\textcolor{white}{\hspace*{5in}\bfseries{\Large Test Of Text Here}}}}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
```

With a new latex you could also put the code in the new shipout/foreground hook. Or you could use eso-pic which has code for the foreground too.

[image]